# caroufredsel not working so well in chrome

Tags: css, jquery-plugins

Using a jquery carousel plug in (http://caroufredsel.frebsite.nl/) which works fine except on chrome/webkit. I have an inner div positioned over each slide, and in chrome, this div disappears after 2-3 slides slide past. Whats going on??

http://goo.gl/wStU0

Answer (score 1):

Didn't figure out quite what the exact issue was but by switching from position:absolute to relative on the inner div and some judicious use of negative margins, made it work-ish.